# Google Sheets Import XML

Tags: google-sheets, importxml

I'm trying to import the price from this products website: https://www.mobilesentrix.com/lcd-assembly-with-steel-plate-pre-installed-replacement-for-iphone-xr-aftermarket-aq7

But struggling to use the formula ImportXML

Does anyone know what the formula is?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
=importxml("https://www.mobilesentrix.com/lcd-assembly-with-steel-plate-pre-installed-replacement-for-iphone-xr-aftermarket-aq7","//*[@id='product-price-90889']/span")
```

Comment: Thanks a million I tried something like that bur for some reason it didn't work. Yours works great thanks a load :)